# Looping through table rows, fetching a total and updating row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know what the problem is, but I am unsure how to fix it.

It is looping through each tr, and then posting to a url to retrieve a total, by the time the post returns a value, the loop has reached the last tr in the table.

So when the .done callback takes place, $tr is referencing the last row in the table.

What is the best approach to reference the original $tr that the post call was made for?

```
        $div.find('table tbody tr').each(function() {
            $tr = $(this);
            associationId = $tr.data('id');

            $.post(settings.UrlFetch, {competition_id: settings.CompetitionId, association_id: associationId})
                .done(function (res) {

                    if (res.success) {
                        $tr.find('.total').html('$' + Number(res.data.total).toFixed(2));
                    } else {
                        alert(res.errors);
                    }
                })
                .fail(function (res) {
                   alert("Unknown Error Occurred");
                });

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using a global variable `$tr` which is overriden in each iteration of the `each` callback, you need to use a closure variable(by declaring `$tr` using `var`) to have a local instance of `$tr` in each call of the callback

```
$div.find('table tbody tr').each(function () {
    var $tr = $(this); //use local variable
    associationId = $tr.data('id');

    $.post(settings.UrlFetch, {
        competition_id: settings.CompetitionId,
        association_id: associationId
    }).done(function (res) {

        if (res.success) {
            $tr.find('.total').html('$' + Number(res.data.total).toFixed(2));
        } else {
            alert(res.errors);
        }
    }).fail(function (res) {
        alert("Unknown Error Occurred");
    });

});
```